# Why does this directive only apply to one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to reveal items as they enter the view when I scroll in my angular app. The problem is that all elements seem to reveal as soon as the first element reveals. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/nETvkzqKZvak5B6I4QpV

Update: I got it working. Does anyone have any ideas on how to improve performance. It's very jumpy.

```
   .directive("scrollFade", function($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
        var bottom_of_object = $(element).offset().top + $(element).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (bottom_of_object < bottom_of_window) {  
          //in view  
          element.css('opacity', 1);
        } else { 
          //outside of view
          element.css('opacity', 0);
        }
        scope.$apply();
      });
    };
  });
```

Comment: can you create a plunker or jsfiddle do demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's plnkr related but I'm getting an undefined position error: http://plnkr.co/edit/nETvkzqKZvak5B6I4QpV

Comment: @EliteOctagon Update, I got it working but it's very jumpy. Thanks for your reply. Making the plnkr was helpful.

Comment: I think you just need to apply a [css transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565587/css-transition-opacity-on-mouse-out) to the elements.

Comment: Yea, I had a transition but it's still a bit laggy. Might just be my computer.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hcpddgp0zu0fitCfNMLb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like debounce from lodash or underscore library (http://lodash.com/docs#debounce), that can improve your performance a bit.